# JOIN two SELECT queries, leaving ALL element from first table even without corrispondence

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I need help in joining two select in a Sqlite database.

I would like to list all elements of the first table even if there is no corrispondence in the second table... I write down the tables beacuse I don't know how to explain well in words...

These are my tables:

**tab1**

[image]

**tab2**

[image]

**expected result**

[image]

My query is:

```
SELECT tab1.ID, tab1.email, tab1.email2, tab2.name
FROM tab1
LEFT JOIN tab2
WHERE tab2.email LIKE tab1.email
   OR tab2.email LIKE tab1.email2
```

...and what I get is: NOTHING...

**Note: I made all tables in markdown but I always get this error**

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Very frustrating doing this post!

Comment: Change `WHERE` to `ON`

Comment: Done, but I get "name" column empty. I am able to get the name only if `tab2.email` is equal to `tab1.email` or `tab1.email2`.Should "LIKE" give results if tab1.email is present as a substring of tab2.email?

Comment: To format tables: Write your data in proper columns. Highlight. Click `{}`.

Comment: If you use LIKE without wildcards then that is the same as =

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `instr` function?

```
select a.id, a.email, a.email2, b.name
from tab1 a left join tab2 b on instr(b.email, a.email)  > 0
                             or instr(b.email, a.email2) > 0
order by a.id;
```

Result is

```
ID  EMAIL                   EMAIL2                  NAME
--  --------------------    ---------------------   ------
1   pippo@example.com       pippo2@example.com      Pippo
2   pluto@example.com       null                    Pluto
3   paperino@example.com    mrpaperino@example.com  null
4   franco@example.com      null                    null
5   null                    mario@rossi.com         Mario
```

Have a look at [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Pf0B945S).